# Override "ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries" and force PostGIS to do the query

Tags: postgis, srid

I'm trying to do an `st_intersects` query in postgis for two shapes (a point and buffer zone) which are of the same projected coordinate system.

Unfortunately, one of the tables seems to have its table-srid value set to 4326. And yes, the first spatial column added to that table (`airports`) **was** of the geographic type (srid=4326). However, that same table has a column in it (added later) which is of the projected coordinate system (srid=2264) that I'm working with.

When I try to run this query:

```
a = Airport.first
WakeCountyParcel.where{st_intersects(proj_shape, st_buffer(a.cary_proj_point, 5280))}
```

where cary_proj_point is the projected coordinate point (srid=2264) as is WakeCountyParcel's proj_shape, I get the SRID error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries
```

To get around this I simply reconstruct Airport's `cary_proj_point` to divorce its association from the tainted Airport model

```
cary_proj_point = RGeo::Geos.factory(:srid => 2264).parse_wkt(a.cary_proj_point.as_text)
WakeCountyParcel.where{st_intersects(proj_shape, st_buffer(cary_proj_point, 5280))}
```

and all is well. In fact, rails being what it is, I could abstract out all of this code and, say, create a model method for `Airport` that would return the reconstructed projected point without me ever even having to look at the string-based reconstruction again.

But its a hack and forcing PostGIS to do it anyway without having to trick it would be nice. I furthermore disagree with the concept of having one table per SRID value. I want my database to have geographic and projected spatial objects in different columns of the same table(s) for convenience. How do I over-ride PostGIS's pedagogic error of forcing one-SRID per table here?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the relevant rows from the geometry_columns table? Because you did use addGeometryColumn didn't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to replace this construction

```
st_intersects(proj_shape, st_buffer(cary_proj_point, 5280))
```

with this one

```
st_dwithin(proj_shape, cary_proj_point, 5280)
```

(because otherwise you'll have a terrible scalability problem in the future) and it will won't give you the answer you want unless proj_shape and cary_proj_point both have SRID = 2264. Do they?

Comment: They do have the same srid. The airport model also has a column with `cary_proj_point`'s location data stored in WGS84 (srid:4326), but `cary_proj_point` is of the same projected coordinate system as `WakeCountyParcel`'s `proj_shape`

Comment: Basically, I have a model (here, `Airport`) whose **source data** (i.e. its shapefile) was originally WGS84 but has been also converted into NAD83 (North Carolina 3000 feet) (2264) in the `cary_proj_shape` column. The table `airports` has two columns representing two distinct projected coordinate systems. PostGIS does not respect this and is throwing an error.

Comment: Without looking at your system directly, there's not much more I can say. PostGIS of course is not throwing this error for fun, there are truly differing SRIDs somewhere, this check has been in place for years, it's not something new. Turn on statement logging in PostgreSQL and get the ACTUAL SQL that Ruby is generating and see if it makes sense, if the columns being referenced do in fact have geometries of the same SRID.

Comment: Oh, and run "SELECT DISTINCT ST_SRID(proj_shape) FROM yourTAble" and "SELECT DISTINCT ST_SRID(cary_proj_point) FROM yourTable)". See that they're the same in all instances.

Comment: `WakeCountyParcel.connection.select_value("SELECT DISTINCT ST_SRID(proj_shape) FROM wake_county_parcels")`#=> 2264

Comment: `UsaAirport.connection.select_value("SELECT DISTINCT ST_SRID(cary_proj_point) FROM usa_airports")` #=> 2264

Comment: (now for the geographic point) `UsaAirport.connection.select_value("SELECT DISTINCT ST_SRID(proj_point) FROM usa_airports")` #=> `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function st_srid(geography) does not exist`

Comment: You're going to have to look at the log file to see the generated SQL. The SRID test is done geometry by geometry, there is no table-level influence on that, so I suspect Ruby is doing something "smart" somewhere.

Comment: so the st_dwithin thing, why is that? I'm guessing it would be because st_intersects & st_buffer allocate a lot (OK, not a lot, but at large scales its a lot) of unnecessary memory (st_buffer) that is rapidly disposed of a second after the moment it is created & processing power (st_intersects) compared to st_dwithin which uses less? Is there some location where I can find query optimization statistics for postgis methods?

Comment: ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer()) both builds a buffer (which is computationally very expensive) and performs a full intersection test (which is somewhat expensive) while ST_DWithin() just has to perform a distance test (relatively cheap). ST_DWithin() also wraps up an index operator, which the other method cannot easily do.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing an operation of intersectacion ST_INTERSECTS between two different projections geometries (SRID), which causes the problem
what to do is transform a geometry to the same projection of the other geometry with which you want to intersect using:

st_transform(geometria, newsrid)

Comment: No, I'm not. The two shapes I'm doing an operation for have the same projected coordinate system. One of the table's srid values is set to 4326, but the column I'm operating with in that table is of the same PCS as the other table. If I were to transform anything it would be inaccurate.

Comment: You and the database, however, are clearly on the same page. If you and the database were correct, it would be a different story.